# Units of the rate of change of the area with respect to a linear measure

Tags: derivatives, area, unit-of-measure

Suppose we have:

> Find the instantaneous rate of change of the area of a square with respect to its side when the side is $2\,\textrm{cm}$.

**Solution**. 
Let $a$ be the side of the square. Then $A=a^2$ is the respective area and 
$$
\dfrac{\textrm{d}A}{\textrm{d}a} = \dfrac{\textrm{d}}{\textrm{d}a}(a^2) = 2a.
$$
Finally,
$$
\left.\dfrac{\textrm{d}A}{\textrm{d}a}\right|_{a=2} = 4.
$$

Now, the question:

> Is it $4\,\textrm{cm}$? I mean the units :) Or it would be better to say $\textrm{cm}^2/\textrm{cm}$?

The later is the same as $\textrm{cm}$, but since we are asking about the rate of change in the area, maybe we should keep it as $\textrm{cm}^2/\textrm{cm}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, the unit is simply $\mathrm{cm}$, yes.

However, for ease of understanding, I would say $\mathrm{cm}^2/\mathrm{cm}$ is better, as it gives a clear understanding of what is happening - that is we are giving the change of area (in $\mathrm{cm}^2$) per change of length (in $\mathrm{cm}$).